# Apparent mistake in review audit system

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

As you all may know, when reviewing other people's posts we get the tricky question every once in a while (I think it's like one in ten or something like that) to see if we're paying attention. I got audited, I was paying attention and either I'm missing something or the system was wrong. I marked this edit as accepted, it said it was rejected for vandalism and that I should pay more attention.

[image]

I'd really rather not get flagged for incorrect reviews while doing things right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The one in your screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2447899) is not an audit:

[image]

[This is the audit you failed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2447773):

[image]

Comment: Didn't even see it, so I guess I'll stop reviewing.. Thanks!